# Ghost Swipe up iPhone X after screen replacement

Tags: iphone, screen

My girlfriend breaks her iPhone X at least 2 times per year, so after having spent 630€ at the Apple Store in one year I started to change her screen by myself.

With today I did it 5 times, but a strange thing happened; the screen functions well but sometimes the iPhone do a “ghost swipe down” by itself.

So I am asking if this is something that I can fix by myself (maybe opening and closing it again, moving the screen cables etc.) or if the problem is probably the screen that is defective.

Is there an error in assembly that could result in this problem?

Comment: Buy bad screens, get bad results.  It's past time to either put her phone in a case, or stop taking responsibility for it.

Comment: That phone needs a fully armored protection case. And it's either cheap parts or repairer error since it has been replaced correctly before, so either do it again or get it done properly.

Comment: You need a original display. And a Display what is make for the hardware and that can only Apple.

Comment: @SolarMike the phone has a very rough armored case, but if you drop it at lest 4/5 times per day, it will breaks a day or another.

Comment: @MarcWilson the replacement screen is not bad, maybe this one is defective yes, but 1 of 5 it’s ok, I still have warranty anyway. With 300€ I bought 5 screens, with the same amount I will have just bought one from Apple, that would have break in 6 months anyway, at least these lasted 2 year.

Comment: @DarwinOSX same

Comment: @AndreaDiPinto You are an enabler.  Stop being one.  Since you have taken responsibility for her phone, she will not change her behavior.